# How to get mailcatcher to work with rbenv, bundler, and ruby 3.2.0?

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv, activesupport, mailcatcher

I've completely removed rvm and installed 0.5.10 of mailcatcher.  When I run mailcatcher I get the following error:

```
.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111:in `<class:BigDecimal>': undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)
    BigDecimal.new('4.56').dup
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: Provide a full script that you have a trouble with please. Gem mailcatcher works on Ruby 3.2 - this version in CI matrix of the repository. So, the reason of fail probably somewhere in your environment.

Comment: Why does it have to be MailCatcher 0.5.10? That's pretty old as is ActiveSupport 3.2

Comment: @VasilyKolesnikov the error only happens when I run mailcatcher.  Installation succeeds, but I don't know what script I could provide you to better help with answer.

Comment: @muistooshort It doesn't have to be mailcatcher.  I'd be interested in any solution that involved intercepting e-mail and redisplaying the HTML email in a browser.  Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I did some more digging and found https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog?ref=stackshare which satisfies my needs.

Comment: I use MailCatcher with Ruby 3.2, just a more recent version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mailcatcher version `0.5.10` was released [in September 2012](https://rubygems.org/gems/mailcatcher/versions/0.5.10), more than 10 years ago. And this ancient version requires `activesupport ~> 3.0` which is part of Ruby on Rails and therefore adding it to your `Gemfile` and running Bundler, downgraded your application's Rails version to the latest `3.2` version.

To fix this problem, I suggest adding Mailcatcher to your `Gemfile` without specifying any version, like this

```
gem 'mailcatcher'
```

and running `bundle install` again.

That should install the latest version of the Mailcatcher gem (`0.8.2` at the time of writing this answer) which should run fine with up-to-date versions of Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Alas, I am not running Ruby on Rails.  It's for a nodejs project, but thank you for the answer.  I chose to go with MailHog instead, because it just worked out of the box.  That way I don't have to put a Gemfile in my project or use Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it in your gemfile then what worked for me after upgrading to Ruby 3 and rails 7 was to use the latest beta version with `gem install mailcatcher --pre`.